# LINQ - How to write a query, when the model has a list property?

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm developing the database tables in C# (ASP.NET Core API). Two tables have one-to-many relationship (one `Order` has many `ToBeOrdered`). Info: these are only two tables, not all.
The problem is, when I try to create an `Order` element, which has to contain one or many elements from `ToBeOrdered` table, the program will actually create many `Order`s each containing one `ToBeOrdered` element and not a list.

`Order` model:

```
[Key]
public string Id { get; set; }

public string SupplierId { get; set; }
public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }

public List<ToBeOrdered> ToBeOrdered { get; set; }
```

`ToBeOrdere` model:

```
[Key]
public string Id { get; set; }
[Required]
public int Quantity { get; set; }

public string ProductId { get; set; }
public Product Product { get; set; }

public string ProjectId { get; set; }
public Project Project { get; set; }

public string OrderId { get; set; }
public Order Order { get; set; }
```

Query:

```
public IEnumerable<Order> CreateOrder(string supplierId)
    {
        IEnumerable<Order> result =
            from tbo in _context.ToBeOrdered
            join p in _context.Products
                on tbo.ProductId equals p.Id
            where p.SupplierId == supplierId
            select new Order
            {
                SupplierId = supplierId,
                ToBeOrdered = new List<ToBeOrdered> {tbo}
            };

        return result;
    }
```

`Order` model result for example:

```
[
{
    "id": "7deeb60b-e9b4-4925-ac39-7dd983df5f24",
    "supplierId": "c76e873d-6bcd-4f97-bacc-a7c55b813d06",
    "supplier": null,
    "toBeOrdered": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "quantity": 10,
            "productId": "bb4f5a16-1d6e-483c-89f5-7d16ba357691",
            "product": null,
            "projectId": "068e61cf-50b6-4669-9709-cd279b26ecf3",
            "project": null,
            "orderId": null,
            "order": null
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "a186887c-6009-4e18-a81a-5b40f8f0ba06",
    "supplierId": "c76e873d-6bcd-4f97-bacc-a7c55b813d06",
    "supplier": null,
    "toBeOrdered": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "quantity": 20,
            "productId": "bb4f5a16-1d6e-483c-89f5-7d16ba357691",
            "product": null,
            "projectId": "068e61cf-50b6-4669-9709-cd279b26ecf3",
            "project": null,
            "orderId": null,
            "order": null
        }
    ]
}
]
```

In the result should be only one `Order` with two `ToBeOrdered` models in the list.
What should I change in the LINQ query?

Comment: `ToBeOrdered = tbo.Order.ToBeOrdered` ?

Comment: no. Unfortunately it's not good.

Comment: Is lazy loading enabled? If yes then mark your List to be virtual.
public virtual List<ToBeOrdered> ToBeOrdered { get; set; } and forget about the join. Just load your Orders from db. ToBeOrdered will be populated accordingly. Don't forget to add the [foreignkey] attribute.

Comment: Why not set up your relationship in the model/database and then you need to query the top level only?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
public IEnumerable<Order> CreateOrder(string supplierId)
    {
       return  _context.Set<Order>()
           .Include(i=i.ToBeOrdered);
            .Where(i=> i.SupplierId == supplierId)
            ToArray();
    }
```